# Wasn't Agent Poindexter suspended when he tried to use his FBI credentials?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

In Daredevil S03E08, when the police arrives at Dex's house responding to a 911 call wherein Matt and Agent Nadeem had entered his house, he claims to be an FBI agent, and requests the police officer to check his ID in the wallet in his pocket.

But wasn't he suspended from the FBI earlier in the show? How come he still had a badge to float around, misusing it to his benefit?

Answer (score 4):

> But wasn't he suspended from the FBI earlier in the show?

## Not Quite

He was placed on **Leave** pending the outcome of the shooting investigation, in fact he's told to treat it as a "paid vacation".

Certainly he surrenders his belt badge and gun but that doesn't mean he's actually suspended which is more *punitive* than leave.

> How come he still had a badge to float around, misusing it to his benefit?

### He didn't

He specifically refers to his ID which isn't the same as a **badge** although these often go together in the same ID wallet/folder, like so.

[image]

We see him surrender his badge (or at least his belt badge) but he'd still be entitled to carry around the ID portion since, until he's actually fired.

Comment: Good question, superb answer, amazing season (I would rate this alongside S4 of Agents Of S.H.E.I.L.D as the best TV content to come from the MCU to date)

Comment: It seems like Hattley was just sugarcoating his suspension, because later, when Nadeem introduces Poindexter to his attorney friend, they talk about suing the FBI for wrongful suspension and she also mentions getting him back pay. - And why take the badge, but not the paper ID? Isn't the point of surrendering the badge that one can no longer ID oneself as a member of the FBI/Police? If the paper ID is just as valid, then why even bother taking the badge?